# Exception Field 'DISCRIMINATOR' doesn't have a default value

Tags: hibernate

I have the following mapping files.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="One" abstract="true">
       <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
         <discriminator column="DISCRIMINATOR" type="string" />

        <union-subclass name="Two" table="TWO">
        .
        .
        </union-subclass>
        <union-subclass name="Three" table="THREE">
        .
        .
        </union-subclass>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass name="TWOSUB" extends="TWO">
        .
        .
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to add object of TWOSUB, it raises the following exception
Field 'DISCRIMINATOR' doesn't have a default value.

What is wrong with the above mapping?

Comment: have you tried with <discriminator column="DISCRIMINATOR" type="string" default="defaultvalue"/>  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add discriminator-value="YOUR_CUSTOM_SUBCLASS_DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE" to all class tags that are distinguished from each other by using a discriminator (and which are therefore mapped in the same table). Otherwise hibernate does not know which discriminator value to use to distinguish them.

However, i don't think that it is possible to extend a union-subclass with a subclass that uses a discriminator - you either have to use another union-subclass for your class TWOSUB, or you don't use union-subclass at all for inheriting TWO from ONE. At least there is no discriminator-value attribute for union-subclass tags and therefore it is not possible to distinguish between TWO and TWOSUB.